# What service uses UDP port 242?

Tags: port

What service uses UDP port 242? 
According to nmap, it says that the service or protocol named "direct" uses the port, but Google search does not seem to bring me an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was once assigned to Herb Sutter for Peer-Direct (PDRE). Peer-Direct was an application to replicate databases. UDP and TCP ports are assigned together, but PDRE *never* used UDP for any purpose. So it is basically free for anyone to use for any purpose.

Any service could use it. No service that I know of typically uses it.

Comment: IANA registered ports reference: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

Comment: The Peer Direct application to replicate databases was renamed DXRE and is now owned by DXSTRO. The ports are still registered, and in use by thousands of servers worldwide. Currently DXRE only uses TCP port.