# What service uses UDP port 1049

Tags: port

Just curious:

nmap scan shows me the UDP port 1049 open, and label it as td-postman.

What could be using the UDP port 1049? (search on td-postman reveals me some vpmn stuff and searching it by that name does not bring me anything..)

Comment: [Check Daniel Beck's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/466799/what-service-uses-udp-port-242#comment549191_466800)

Comment: My bet is someone just randomly chose port 1049.

Answer (score 1):

It's assigned to German [Tobit Software](http://www.tobit.com/)'s David product as per the [IANA reference of assigned ports](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt).

```
Service Name   Port Number Protocol          Description                               Assignee                                               Contact 
td-postman         1049        tcp    Tobit David Postman VPMN     [Franz_Josef_Leuders]                              [Franz_Josef_Leuders]
td-postman         1049        udp    Tobit David Postman VPMN     [Franz_Josef_Leuders]                              [Franz_Josef_Leuders]
```